# Actionscript 3 Casting object to class returns null

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm having a problem with AS3. I'm trying to cast an object, but it returns null. However, I'm absolutely positive that the object's class is the one I'm casting to:

```
    trace(example);
returns [class exampleClass]
```

. However, casting it like so:

```
    trace(example as exampleClass);
returns null;
```

Is there any reason as to why this can be the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that `example` isn't actually an object, it is a reference to the `class` `exampleClass`

You probably did something like `var example = exampleClass` instead of `var example = new exampleClass()`

Comment: Ah, I suspected something along the lines of this! I was using an experimental framework, so I wasn't exactly sure of the implementation, just used the API. I guess 'new' was ommited :3

Comment: In which case you do example is exampleClass